# Getting debugger command from active project configuration

Tags: vsix

In a VSIX package I have to get the debugger command for active startup configuration. In other words, the command that would be executed when 'sturt under debugger' is selected. Using the code below I was able to get active configuration for startup project, but I can't figure out how to get the debugger command from IVSHierarchy representing the startup project. Is this even possible without going back to DTE?

```
private void GetStartupProject()
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        IVsSolutionBuildManager bm = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsSolutionBuildManager)) as IVsSolutionBuildManager;
        int hr;
        IVsHierarchy project;
        hr = bm.get_StartupProject(out project);
        if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK)
        {
            project.GetProperty((uint)VSConstants.VSITEMID.Root, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_Name, out object projectName);
            IVsProjectCfg[] activeCfgs = new IVsProjectCfg[1];
            bm.FindActiveProjectCfg(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, project, activeCfgs);
            activeCfgs[0].get_DisplayName(out string activeCfgName);
            textOut.Text += String.Format("{0} {1}\r\n",(string)projectName, activeCfgName);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time debugging and with help from Ed Dore, I was able to put together code that gets complete debugging command and working dir for native C++ and managed code projects:

```
    private void ListStartupProperties()
    {
        ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
        IVsHierarchy vsHierarchy = null;
        int hresult = bm.get_StartupProject(out vsHierarchy);
        object objProject = null;
        if(vsHierarchy != null)
            hresult = vsHierarchy.GetProperty((uint)VSConstants.VSITEMID.Root, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out objProject);
        Project startupProject = (Project)objProject;

        if (startupProject != null)
        {
            foreach (Property prop in startupProject.Properties)
            {
                try
                {
                    textOut.Text += string.Format("{0} = {1}\r\n", prop.Name, prop.Value);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    textOut.Text += e.Message + "\r\n";
                }
            }
            string cmd = "";
            string args = "";
            string wd = "";
            VCProject vcp = startupProject.Object as VCProject;
            if (vcp != null)
            {   // This is VC project
                VCConfiguration vcc = vcp.ActiveConfiguration;
                VCDebugSettings dbg = vcc.DebugSettings;
                cmd = vcc.Evaluate(dbg.Command);
                args = vcc.Evaluate(dbg.CommandArguments);
                wd = vcc.Evaluate(dbg.WorkingDirectory);
            }
            else
            {   // Probably C# or VB
                Configuration cfg = startupProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
                ProjectConfigurationProperties cfgProperties = cfg.Object as ProjectConfigurationProperties;
                if (cfgProperties != null)
                {
                    string outPath = cfgProperties.OutputPath;
                    string localPath = startupProject.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value as string;
                    string outputName = startupProject.Properties.Item("OutputFileName").Value as string;
                    cmd = cfgProperties.StartProgram != "" ? 
                        cfgProperties.StartProgram :
                        localPath + outPath + outputName;
                    args = cfgProperties.StartArguments;
                    wd = cfgProperties.StartWorkingDirectory;
                }
            }
            textOut.Text += string.Format("StartProgram = {0}\r\n", cmd);
            textOut.Text += string.Format("StartArguments = {0}\r\n", args);
            textOut.Text += string.Format("WorkingDir = {0}\r\n", wd);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [IVsProjectCfg interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprojectcfg) doesn't allow for enumerating the various configuration properties, or contain a method that would allow you to retrieve them. As you probably already suspect, the various project types expose their settings via automation, which for C# and VB.NET projects would correlate to using EnvDTE/VSLangProj interfaces to retrieve the specific debugger properties for a given configuration. For C#/VB.NET projects you'll want to retrieve/use the [ProjectConfigurationProperties3 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/vslangproj80.projectconfigurationproperties3). For example:

```
private void OnGetDebuggerSettings(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    IVsHierarchy vsHierarchy = null;
    IVsSolutionBuildManager slnBuildMgr = (IVsSolutionBuildManager)GetService(typeof(SVsSolutionBuildManager));
    int hresult = slnBuildMgr.get_StartupProject(out vsHierarchy);
    object objProject = null;
    hresult = vsHierarchy.GetProperty((uint)VSConstants.VSITEMID.Root, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out objProject);
    Project startupProject = (Project)objProject;

    // Note, cannot enumerate the ProjectConfigurationProperties, as it's not a collection interface
    // Refer to the documentation for ProjetConfigurationProperties3, or set a BP on the WriteLine below
    // and view the Dynamic View of the cfgProperties in the debugger's locals or watch window.
    Configuration cfg = startupProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
    ProjectConfigurationProperties3 cfgProperties = cfg.Object as ProjectConfigurationProperties3;
    if (cfgProperties!=null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cfgProperties.StartArguments);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that'll get you up and running.

Comment: Thank you for the post, Ed. This is really helpful. This doesn't work for VC projects however. Another problem is that if start program not specified in the project settings, it comes up empty in cfgProperties. I have addressed those issues in a separate code fragment and published it as an alternative answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Hi Ed, this looks good for a classic C# project, but for an "Sdk-style" one (e.g., one for .NET Core), most of the properties just throw NotImplementedException. I've had a hard time finding the right interface to enumerate those; specifically, I'm hoping to somehow find the currently-picked launchSettings.json (the "Startup Profile", it appears to be called).